# Why does htop show half of the memory that the same machine on windows shows?

Tags: htop

was out exploring in the binary jungle and found that my htop on Ubuntu WSL2 showed half the memory that windows shows. So, I'm running a 32GB machine, but htop only admits it having 16GB. Anyone know what's the deal with this?

[image: htop on windows system for Linux 2]

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. If the subsystem was using 100% of your memory, then there would be no memory left for your system. A relative [SU post](https://superuser.com/a/1328662/701993) suggests that 50% is usually used for WSL2. It is also configurable as you see into that post.